# Creating a linked server in SSMS via SSH connection to localhost (WordPress - MariaDB)

Tags: sql, ssh, mariadb, ssms, linked-server

We have a wordpress site which we would like to create a linked server for to enable us to query the database in SSMS.

The webserver has a username,password and seperate IP which allows us to logon via ssh.

The database is a localhost database which has standard dbname/username/password information requirements.

We have tried using the SSMS create linked server wizard however we have not been able to connect even after much googling.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below article to create mysql Linked server in MS SQL:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/